# BLE device services showing null in uiAvailableServices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am successfully connecting to a BLE device. I am trying to get all of it's services and add them to an array. However when I go to loop through them in uiAvailableServices, it is showing up null.

Code that calls available services

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mBleWrapper == null) mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, this);

    if(!mBleWrapper.initialize()) {
        finish();
    }

    // start automatically connecting to the device
    mBleWrapper.connect(mDeviceAddress);

    uiAvailableServices(mBleWrapper.getGatt(), mBleWrapper.getDevice(), mBleWrapper.getCachedServices());

}
```

The availableservices function:

```
   //add each service to the services array
    public void uiAvailableServices(final BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                final BluetoothDevice device,
                                final List<BluetoothGattService> services)
    {
    //services aren't showing up here
    for (BluetoothGattService service : services)
    {
        String uuid = service.getUuid().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        Log.d(TAG, uuid);

    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Why should there be any cached services? You create a new mBleWrapper object, initialize it and connect to the remote device. That's all. How could there be any services already? What does getCachedServices do?

Comment: getCachedServices is in the blewrapper, it just returns the services. I thought uiAvaiableServices is what finds them but I see now how that doesn't make sense. Do you know what function typically collects all services in ble apps?

Comment: I've been following a tutorial that says it automatically adds services upon connection: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch08.html#_communicating_with_a_remote_device

Comment: I do not know how it works specifically in your framework, and the link hides the information behind a paywall. Normally, after connection you have to start a discovery of the services. Only after this discovery you can work with the services of the remote device. I find it questionable if the function "connect" also conducts a discovery afterwards, as this would mingle two very different actions. Also, one might choose to only discover a part of the services, only the primary services, only a specific service etc.

Comment: So my advice would be to check if there are any methods that are named "discovery" or "discoverServices" or something like that. These should specify the parameters for discovery and also populate a list of services that you can access afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't need the line

```
uiAvailableServices(mBleWrapper.getGatt(), mBleWrapper.getDevice(), mBleWrapper.getCachedServices());
```

This line is used in part to retrieve characteristics from the service.